# How to trigger workflow action if it touches certain file or is a Pull Request with a certan file

Tags: github, github-actions, building-github-actions

I have the following action:

```yaml
name: Run after changing anything in myPath package
on:
  pull_request:
  push:
    paths:
      - 'myPath/**'
```

This action runs when something is pushed under `myPath` but also on any pull request.

How I can limit this action to pull requests that contain changes under `myPath`?

Comment: You can use the `paths` for `pull_request` trigger as well, the same way you did for the `push` trigger:   ```pull_request:
    paths:
      - 'myPath/**'``` as explained on the first paragraph from this section on the official documentation: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestpull_request_targetpathspaths-ignore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to repeat `paths` for each event type.

```
name: Run after changing anything in myPath package
on:
  pull_request:
    paths:
      - 'myPath/**'
  push:
    paths:
      - 'myPath/**'
```